# Can you write to memcached only if key does not exist

Tags: memcached

The use case is to generate a unique key, I want to be able to do something like this

```
while !memcache.write_if_not_exist(key, value, :expires_in => 1.minute)
  key = generate_new_key
end
```

where write_if_not_exist will not write value and return false if the key already exists in memcached.

Answer (score 1):

answering my own questions here, after researching the memcached protocol. the "add" command does exactly that.

https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt